# The "microsoft-metro" tag should be renamed to "microsoft-modern-ui"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

With Microsoft dropping the Metro UI keyword due to trademark issues with a company in Europe. I think the "microsoft-metro" tag in StackOverflow should also be renamed to its correct term. Since Microsoft calls its Modern UI, the tag should also be named appropriately as (maybe) "microsoft-modern-ui"

Comment: IMO pretty much everyone except MS might keep calling it Metro (I sure do) so I don't see the value to switching to their laughably bad placeholder name.

Comment: @BenBrocka: However "laughably bad" the name is (and it is bad), that's what they're calling it. They're the ones who created it, so they're the ones who decide what it gets called in their official documentation for their tech. It may be (and is) stupid, but that's what they're calling it. For us to retain the "Metro UI" term would just be creating confusion after a while. C++0x when through the same thing when it was ratified into C++11.

Comment: @NicolBolas IS it what they're calling it? They've [increasingly downplayed the fact that it has a name at all](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/blog/2012/aug/14/windows-8-metro-microsoft-newspeak?CMP=twt_gu). I have a strong suspicion that it will eventually just not have a name if they don't end up going back to Metro (the only actually recognizable name)

Answer (score 6):

[modern-ui](/questions/tagged/modern-ui) may become old-ui one day. Should be something more persistent, something like [windows-8-ui-style](/questions/tagged/windows-8-ui-style)?

Also, I'm against renaming; [microsoft-metro](/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) better be kept as a synonym.

Comment: +1 for the synonym but it's not just windows 8, it applies to Windows phone 7, Visual Studio 2012 on any platform, etc, etc

Comment: While "Modern UI" is a terrible product name, we should use whatever the official terminology is instead of making up a term of our own no matter how inane the official terms may be.

Comment: I like your way of calling it, sounds better. But like @AnnaLear said we should go with the official terminology. Maybe [tag:microsoft-modern-ui] is not appropriate, but name close to what MS calls it should (and I believe, must) be used to avoid confusion. For users who know the metro term must get used to the new term as it is no longer official and for new users to microsoft's use interface they will know the UI by its offical term.

Comment: I would also wait to see what shakes out after the official Win8 launch, MS may well end up licencing 'metro' or using it anyway if it doesn't infringe. In any case it needs to stay becuase the term is in popular use, regardless of its current situation.